# How to add a extra products fields on ubercart check out pane table?

Tags: 7, ubercart

Hi im looking to add some extra fields on the check out pane, i mean fields from the product like some attributes, theres any possibility?

Please if someone how to do this let me know!

Thank's to everyone who can help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go for [Ubercart Webform Integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_webform)

```
This module integrates two other modules: webform and ubercart. It allows you sell 
products directly from your webforms. It is particularly suited to be used as part of a 
registration system.
```